# PHP SOAP call working in development but not in production

Tags: php, wordpress, soap, wsdl, nusoap

Why would a php nusoap getProxy() (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) call to a development webservice (splendid) return an object in my development environment, and return NULL in production? I am also able to make a call to the production webservice from my development machine (but I can't make a call from the production machine to the production webservice).

We are using IIS, the same version of wordpress, the same plugin, the same version of php, and the same source code:

```
$this->client = new nusoap_client(SPLENDID, true, false, false, false, false, 0, 30, '');
$proxy = $this->client->getProxy(); // getype($proxy) returns object in development
                  //and NULL in production
```

I understand that you probably can't pinpoint the exact problem, but ANY pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try getting the error message: `$msg = $this->client->getError();`

Comment: It's possible that PHP, running in the context of your IIS site, cannot call out to the Splendid WSDL and download it. You might want to make sure you can access that URL in PHP on the production server.

Comment: We are able to access the URL from the production server, so that can't be the issue.

Comment: And the error message says: "A proxy can only be created for a WSDL client"... which is weird because that's exactly what we are working with.

Comment: Are you testing for connectivity from within the service account that hosts your PHP instance or your own login? They can be different.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of IIS Server settings. I made .Net helpers which ended up telling me the error.